# transform: scale clipping

Tags: css, transform, scale

I am trying to use transform: scale for a grid of images here http://movies.themodern-nerd.com/genre. It works fine when scrolling from left to right, the image that is hover will stay on top of the others, but if you hover from right to left the hovered image is under the image on the right.

```
.searchresults img {
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 2s;
-o-transition-duration: 2s;
transition-duration: 2s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;

overflow:hidden;

}

.searchresults img:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 5px #d50000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 5px #d50000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 5px #d50000;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1); 
-o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
.searchresults:hover {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

But this is not tested, you should create a jsfiddle so we can better help you.

Comment: I just realized that this did fix the layer issue but not at the end of the transition the image makes a small jump. Any idea how to fix this? Also the image blurs when transitioning and after the "jump" the blur is gone.

Comment: This is because the image shifts into low-quality rendering when it's being transformed and shifts back into high quality rendering when the transition has completed. This is "working as intended" (although it's crappy)